# Дочерний div внутри родителя на всю высоту экрана , не больше не меньше. Но без 100vh

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Прошу помощи. Вначале код

```css
html, body {
width: 100%; 
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #cccccc;
}

.container {
background: green; 
height: 100%;
}

header {
z-index: 1;
position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; height: 48px; width: 100%;
background: red
}

.data {
display: flex;
color: #fff;
background: black;
min-height: 100%;
}

main {
position: relative;
min-height: 100%;
background: cyan;
flex-grow: 1;
}

.nav {
width: 100%;
background: lightgreen;
}

.content {
background: #10d1a6;
width: 100%;
}

aside {
background: yellow;
width: 200px;
}

footer {
background: magenta;
z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="container"> 

 <header>Хедер</header>
 
 <div class="data">

  <main>
   
   <div class="nav">Навигатор</div>
   
   <div class="content">
    Начало<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
    1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
    1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
    1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>Конец
   </div> 
   
  </main>
 
  <aside>Боковина</aside>
 </div>

 <footer>Футер</footer>
 
</div>

</body>
```

Что мне необходимо. Есть шапка `header`, центральный блок `.data` вида flex с двумя дочками лево-право `main` и `aside` и `footer`. Внутри main мне надо разместить два блока друг над другом - `.nav` и `.content`. Условие: блок `nav` должен быть на всю высоту экрана, сразу после него начинается `.content` произвольной высоты. Проблема в том, что нав совсем не хочет слушаться, когда его нет, все хорошо, задуманная блочность соблюдается, как я его вставляю - если его `height: 100%` он, при наличии контента улетает вниз до самого футера, выталкивая контент вне, `min-height: 100%` - его вообще нет. Крайне хочу сделать его без 100vh - ибо с ним геммор с мобильными браузерами начинается, кто то учитывает панель, кто то не учитывает, в общем, 100% высоты по олдскульному хочу, это все понимают одинаково.

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/vYLOvNb - так ?

Comment: нет. нав должен быть внутри main и не выходить наружу

Comment: тогда relative поставь header

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, красивого способа это сделать исключительно при помощи CSS не существует. С другой стороны, припоминаю новость, что вроде бы в Хроме это пофиксили и теперь все мобильные браузеры `100vh` воспринимают одинаково. В общем, сперва рекомендую проверить [по этой странице](https://bokand.github.io/demo/urlbarsize.html) корректность работы, прежде чем приступать к сложным решениям.

Если же сложные решения очень хочется применить, то можно это сделать примерно так:

1) добавить css property `--vh-custom`; добавить стиль `.nav { height: calc(var(--vh-custom) * 100) }`;

2) добавить скрипт, который будет при загрузке и ресайзе считать `window.innerHeight / 100` и обновлять значение переменной `--vh-custom` через `setProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

Так?

```js
const root = document.querySelector(':root');

function calcHeight() {
  const heightWindow = window.innerHeight;
  root.style.setProperty('--myVh', heightWindow/100 + 'px');
}

calcHeight();

window.addEventListener('resize', calcHeight);
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 30px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header,
footer {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

main {
  background-color: rgba(255, 135, 135, 1);
  flex: 1;
}

nav {
  min-height: calc( var(--myVh) * 100 );
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">Header</div>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>Nav</nav>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <div class="container">Footer</div>
</footer>
```